# Regex combine match information of 2 different rows

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to extract the 4x4 matrix data from code via regex to use it in python for futher processing.

The name of the data (a matrix for a 3D postion of a point in space) is in a different row than the transform data that the name should be associated with. If I understood it correctly you use groups (...) for that.

```
name 'Point\d'
```

creates matches for the 3D points I want to capture. how to link the transform data to associated point.

```
(?<=transform).+
```

matches the transform data I want

Problem: The both information are in different rows. You could run 2 different regex matched and then combine them afterwards by combining match1 (name) and match1 (transform) but that would potentially cause problems if the matches dont always align an isn't a elegant way.

Here is the sample text that should be processed:

```
scenegraph {
  name 'Root'
  visible 1
  transform 1.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 1.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 1.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 1.000000000e+00
  geometry 0
  children 2 [
    scenegraph {
      name 'Point1'
      visible 1
      transform 8.133591413e-01 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 8.133591413e-01 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 8.133591413e-01 0.000000000e+00 9.277027100e-02 6.371318848e+03 4.141105652e+02 1.000000000e+00
      geometry {
        vertices 1 4294967295 0
        edges 0
        faces 0
        vertex_attrs 2 [
          attribute {
            name 'align_2d'
            type 'vec2'
            startTime 1.03900000000000000e+03
            initialVals 1 [
              -
            ]
            keys 2 [
              1.03900000000000000e+03 0 1.408942139e+03 7.712362671e+02
              1.08900000000000000e+03 0 8.704575806e+02 9.245101929e+02
            ]
          }
          attribute {
            name 'pts_3d'
            type 'vec3'
            startTime 0.00000000000000000e+00
            initialVals 1 [
              + 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00
            ]
            keys 0 [
            ]
          }
        ]
        edge_attrs 0 [
        ]
        face_attrs 0 [
        ]
        selected 1
      }
      children 0 [
      ]
    }
    scenegraph {
      name 'Point2'
      visible 1
      transform 3.526667595e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 3.526667595e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 0.000000000e+00 3.526667595e+00 0.000000000e+00 -4.233531475e+00 6.362593262e+03 4.306122437e+02 1.000000000e+00
      geometry {
        vertices 1 4294967295 0
        edges 0
        faces 0
        vertex_attrs 2 [
          attribute {
            name 'align_2d'
            type 'vec2'
            startTime 1.04500000000000000e+03
            initialVals 1 [
              -
            ]
            keys 2 [
              1.04500000000000000e+03 0 4.777643433e+02 1.594472809e+02
              1.05300000000000000e+03 0 1.969290161e+02 -1.577421112e+02
            ]
          }
```

Comment: That's not a case where regular expressions can handle this in a robust manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rather fragile method for extracting the data you need:

```
txt='''scenegraph {
  name 'Root'
  visible 1
  ...
'''
items = dict(m.groups() for i in txt.replace('\n','').split('scenegraph {')
    for m in [re.match(r".*\bname '([^']+)'.*\btransform ([0-9.e+\- ]+)",i)]
        if m is not None)
```

Now you have a dict with `(name, transform)` items, you can iterate or access items by key, e.g.:

```
for name, transform in items.items():
    print(name, transform.split())

# Root ['1.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '1.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '1.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '1.000000000e+00']
# Point1 ['8.133591413e-01', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '8.133591413e-01', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '8.133591413e-01', '0.000000000e+00', '9.277027100e-02', '6.371318848e+03', '4.141105652e+02', '1.000000000e+00']
# Point2 ['3.526667595e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '3.526667595e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '3.526667595e+00', '0.000000000e+00', '-4.233531475e+00', '6.362593262e+03', '4.306122437e+02', '1.000000000e+00']
```

You'd be better off using a parser for the data format you have at hand (looks like some variant of JSON/Yaml).

Comment: looks promising, I will look into it tomorrow! Thanks you for the help so far! Unfortunatly I do not know what a parser really is, but I will read into it. Can you use parsing without importing modules in python, because I might have the problem that I cannot import a module like regex, because the code has to get executed from python inside the programm we use?